# How to make a command line node app loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, command-prompt

I would like to make a tiny node app that takes an input, then conditionally returns a response, then goes back to the the prompt, until an exit command is entered.

Specifically, I want to use it to create base 36 time stamps, or convert them. So there'd be three conditions: blank, not blank, or input == "exit". In the blank condition it would return

`Date.now().toString(36)`

when text was entered, it would return

`new Date(parseInt(input, 36))`

and finally if the input == "exit" then it would do something like

`readline.close()`

And after the first two conditions, I'd like the same question / prompt to come up again.

I've been struggling with this for a bit now, and I don't even want to include my muddled code lol!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I finally figured it out! I finally got to understand `readline.prompt()` by finishing up reading the node documentation, which has a great example [here](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_tiny_cli).

Here's what I came up with:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: 'Enter blank for timestamp, timestamp for date or exit> '
});

rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if (line.toLowerCase() === "exit") {
        console.log('\nExiting!\n');
        process.exit(0);        
    } else if (line.trim() === "") {
        console.log(`\n${Date.now().toString(36)}\n`)
    } else {
        console.log(`\n${new Date(parseInt(line, 36)).toString()}\n`)
    }
    rl.prompt();
}).on('close', () => {
    console.log('Exiting!');
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Hopefully this will help someone save some time!!!